# Forward all traffic from interface to internal IP address

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v, sip, mikrotik

We've had a new SIP trunk setup and connected to our Mikrotik router, I need to forward all traffic coming from int ETH2 to an internal IP address of a VM (VM Host is connected to Eth5) for our dialler server. How would I set this up in Winbox? Will I need to forward all traffic from Eth2 to Eth5, and then use a NAT rule to send the traffic to the internal IP address?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault!  This is actually a networking question. If your VM is in fully bridged mode, then it should appear as a device on your physical network.  If not, then you'll need to tell your VM environment to forward ports to that VM from the Host.  The IP address used will be different depending upon the way your VM is connected to these networks.

Comment: Oh, have I posted on the wrong forum? I posted on the networkengineering forum and was told to post here.
So as for how to get the traffic to the host, can I forward traffic from ETH2 to the interface the host is connected to (Eth5) ?

Comment: The forum is correct, you might want to tag it as VM and networking, tho.  I manage networks and VMs, but I'm unfamiliar with WinBox specifically so I can only help in a theoretical way.

Comment: Thanks! I've added some VM tags, there doesn't seem to be a Winbox tag though and I can't create it.

Comment: Yes, you have to get a bit of rep to be able to create tags.  Tags are also heavily managed.  Winbox is a Mikrotik product so your Mikrotik tagt should be enough to attract those knowledgeable about your particular product.